# Matlab: How to save Excel files to the specific folder rather than current folder?

Tags: matlab

I have the below code:

```
for p = 1:numel(C)
    filename = C{p}{1,2};
    if ~isempty(filename{:})
        sprintf('%s.xlsx',filename{:})
        writetable(C{p},sprintf('%s.xlsx',filename{:}))
    end
end
```

I want to save all excel files generated in this code to `"C:\AZAR"` instead of the current folder. I know I must use `fullfile` and add a path to the filename but since I'm not really familiar with Matlab codes I didn't how to do it.

Comment: you don't need to use the low-level `sprintf` to build a file name. Simply concatnate a char-array: `['MyFileName','.xlsx']` or a string `strcat("MyFileName",".xlsx")`. Note that the `strcat()` command is more general as it works with char-arrays and strings, which where introduced in R2017a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess of using `fullfile` is correct. Within the `if/end` block build the file name including the directory more or less as follows:

```
fname = fullfile('C:\', 'AZAR', sprintf('%s.xlsx',filename{:});
writetable(C{p},fname);
```

HTH